# How to fix Java 9 Optional "Cannot return a void result" error message?

Tags: java, java-9

I had a class with a method like this:

```
public class Client {
    
private project.enums.ClientType clientType;

private ClientType clientTypeV2;


    @JsonIgnore
    public Optional<Integer> getCodeClientTypeV2() {
        
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.clientTypeV2).map(ClientType::getCode);
    }

}
```

But I would like to change the logic of this method. I want that if `clientTypeV2` is filled, it returns the `code` for that object. Otherwise, I want it to return the `code` that is in the enum of the `clientType`. How to do this using java 8? I tried the following code but an error message appears `"Cannot return a void result"`

```
@JsonIgnore
public Optional<Integer> getCodeClientTypeV2() {

 return Optional.ofNullable(this.clientTypeV2).ifPresentOrElse(ClientType::getCode, () -> this.clientType.getCode());
}
```

#Edit 1

I tried this:

```
@JsonIgnore
public Integer getCodeClientTypeV2() {

return Optional.ofNullable(this.clientTypeV2)
.map(ClientType::getCode)
.orElse(this.clientType.getCode()) ;

}
```

In debug, although clientTypeV2 is filled, the execution flow is entering inside orElse and giving NullPointerException because the clientType is null. What am I missing?

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(...).map(ClientType::getCode).orElse(clientType)` then the signature must change the return `Integer` instead of `Optional<Integer>`

Comment: but now you dont need to return optional any more, you should just ditch it entirely. just use a ternary or something. just because there is a new feature doesn't mean you have to use it

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Michael. Can you check my #edit 1?

Comment: This is Java 9+.  [`Optional#ifPresentOrElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-) was added with Java 9.

Comment: @LouisBelmont Why do you have the `clientType` field if you never assign anything to it?

Comment: Have a look at `Optional.orElseGet`. On the contrary to `Optional.orElse` will the `Supplier` passed to `Optional.orElseGet` be evaluated only in the "empty" case.

Comment: Or as @Michael said, just use ternary operator.

Comment: With `orElseGet` it might go like this (I did not try to compile it though): `Optional.ofNullable(this.clientTypeV2)
.map(ClientType::getCode)
.orElseGet(this.clientType::getCode) `

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Michal but even using orElseGet the same problem as orElse occur

Comment: With the `orElseGet` either `this.clientTypeV2` is not `null` and then the `orElseGet` does not evaluate `this.clientType.getCode()`. Or the `this.clientTypeV2` is `null` and then `this.clientType.getCode()` is evaluated and needs to return not `null`  value. Is this not your scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different solutions, depending on whether `getCode` can return `null`.

When you don’t want the alternative expression to be evaluated beforehand, you have to use [`orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) instead of `orElse(T other)`.

```java
return Optional.ofNullable(clientTypeV2).map(ClientType::getCode)
    .orElseGet(() -> clientType.getCode());
```

If `getCode` can not return `null` and you only want to deal with the possibility that either `clientTypeV2` or `clientType` can be `null`, you can also use

```java
return Optional.ofNullable(clientTypeV2).orElse(clientType).getCode();
```

or even simpler

```java
return (clientTypeV2 != null? clientTypeV2: clientType).getCode()
```

Common to all solution is the assumption that at least on of `clientTypeV2` or `clientType` is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, if you are using `orElse`, you are returning a constant, guaranteed present **value**.  `orElse` either unwraps the value contained in the `Optional`, or uses the default value you provide instead.

If you don't want to change the method signature, use [`Optional#or`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-) instead. You will have to be intelligent about null checks for your `clientType` object, since if it doesn't exist, you can't rely on it being a concrete returnable thing.

```java
return Optional.ofNullable(this.clientTypeV2)
               .map(ClientType::getCode)
               .or(this.clientType.getCode());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this code doesn't compile